# Estimating sum of n elements by throwing away half of elements

Tags: asymptotics, estimation

I've got a task where i need to proove the asymptotic big-Theta equation:
$$
\log n! = \Theta(n \, \log n)
$$

$
\
$

Since $f(\mathit{n}) \in  \Theta(g(\mathit{n}))$ means that $g(n)\cdot k{_1} \leq f(n) \leq g(n)\cdot k{_2}$, one way i can proove the equation above is to find the coefficients $k{_1}$ and $k{_2}$, considering that $f(n) = \log n! $ and $g(n) = n \, \log n$.

Things are pretty simple with $k{_2}$, because $\log n! = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log i \leq n \, \log n$, so $k{_2} = 1$.

Finding $k{_1}$ is not so obvious. I tried to present $\log i = \log n^{\log{_n} i} = \log{_n} i \cdot \log n$, so we have:
$$ 
\frac{\log n!}{n \, \log n} = \frac{\log n \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log{_n} i }{n \, \log n} =  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log{_n} i }{n}  
$$

So now i have to find $k{_1}$ that fits $k{_1} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log{_n} i \geq n$. I guess and i see that $k{_1} \geq 2$ will do, but i cannot prove it.

In the description of the task it is written that a specific trick may be helpful, namely estimating sum of n elements by throwing away half of it's elements. I'll be grateful for any ideas concerning this matter, even ones that attempt to solve the problem by different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \log i \geq \sum_{i=n/2}^n \log i \geq \left(n-\frac{n}{2}\right)\log\frac{n}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \left(n\log n - n\right) \geq \frac{1}{3}n\log n$$
the last step holding for $n$ sufficiently large.

---

Following the comments, another way to show the (stronger) following statement:
$$
 \ln n! = n\ln n - n +o(n)
$$
(which in particular implies $\log n! = n\log n + o(n\log n)$). This is done by a comparison series/integral, a technique that works usually well (good rule of thumb) for series of the form $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)$ where $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a *monotone* function (and, say, continuous, for the sake of integration). Below is a step-by-step derivation.

Here, set $f=\ln\colon\mathbb{R}_+^\ast\to\mathbb{R}$. As $f$ is increasing, one has that for any fixed $j\in\mathbb{N}^\ast$
$$
\forall x\in[j,j+1],\quad f(j) \leq f(x) \leq f(j+1)
$$
which implies, integrating all three terms between on $[j,j+1]$, an interval of size $1$:
$$
f(j) = \int_j^{j+1} f(j)dx \leq \int_j^{j+1} f(x)dx \leq \int_j^{j+1}f(j+1)dx = f(j+1) \tag{$\dagger$}
$$
Now, since $(\dagger)$ is true for *every* $j\geq 1$, we can sum the inequalities for $j$ ranging from $1$ to $n$:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n f(j) \leq \sum_{j=1}^n \int_j^{j+1} f(x)dx \leq \sum_{j=1}^n f(j+1) 
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n f(j) \leq \int_1^{n+1} f(x)dx \leq \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} f(j) = \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} f(j) \tag{$\ddagger$}
$$
(the last equality coming from the fact that here $f(1)=0$). Rearranging the inequalities of $(\ddagger)$, we obtain
$$
\int_1^{n} f(x)dx \leq \sum_{j=1}^n f(j) \leq \int_1^{n+1} f(x)dx \tag{$\star$}
$$
But recall that a primitive of $\ln$ is known (and equal to $x\mapsto x\ln x - x$), and thus
$$\int_1^x f = x\ln x - x + 1$$
so
that
\begin{align*}
\int_1^{n} f(x)dx &= n\ln n -n +1 = n\ln n - n + o(n)\\
\int_1^{n+1} f(x)dx &= (n+1)\ln (n+1) -n = n\ln (n+1) + \ln(n+1) - n \\
&= n\ln n + \underbrace{n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) + \ln(n+1)}_{=o(n)} - n
\end{align*}
Plugging this back into $(\star)$, we finally get 
$$
n\ln n - n + o(n) \leq \sum_{j=1}^n f(j) \leq n\ln n - n +o(n)
$$
as claimed. $\square$

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exatly what i need.

Comment: As a matter of fact, you can prove (with a different method: comparison series/integral) something slightly stronger, i.e. $$\ln(n!)=n\ln n - n +o(n).$$ (i can elaborate if you want)

Comment: well, though i'm not quite sure if i'll easily comprehend it, that'll be great :)

Comment: @MikhailKononenko: I have edited my answer to give a detailed der8ivation. Let me know if there's anything unclear.